# SAP GUI Context Menu Inaccessable

Tags: c#, sap-gui

I have a SAP GUI interface that works except for the context menus.  In this particular case we are trying to automate adding attachments to equipment masters. The button for this is in a context menu in the title bar.

When I do a Script Recording I get this line for selecting the context menu. This works fine if you run it with the transaction opened.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "%GOS_PCATTA_CREA"
```

When I add this into the c# code for editing the equipment master I get the error 'Method got and invalid argument'.

```
GuiShell objectShell =  (GuiShell)SapSession.FindById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell");

objectShell.SelectContextMenuItem("%GOS_PCATTA_CREA");
```

I am not sure how to get the proper Function Code if it is not '%GOS_PCATTA_CREA'.  This is the only object type that we have not been able to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

After poking at this for several days I figured it out.

The Shell holds a tool bar, seems there is some translation in the VBA code that allows direct access to the tool bar in the shell that C# does not.

The code that works is below. It will open the context menu and then open the attachments dialog.

```
GuiToolbarControl myToolBar = (GuiToolbarControl)SapSession.FindById("wnd[0]/titl/shellcont/shell");

myToolBar.PressContextButton("%GOS_TOOLBOX");

myToolBar.SelectContextMenuItem("%GOS_PCATTA_CREA");
```